# HTML Webpack Plugin and HMR

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Does anybody know how to save an HTML page from HTML Webpack Plugin when Webpack is run in hot mode? It keeps files in its memory, and I want to save them into a file system. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-harddisk-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I've used [html-webpack-harddisk-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-harddisk-plugin) with `watchContentBase: true` configuration on devServer. This reloads the page instead or HMR but serves the purpose.